# Keyword for the outer class from an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

In the following snippet:

```
public class a {
    public void otherMethod(){}
    public void doStuff(String str, InnerClass b){}
    public void method(a){
        doStuff("asd",
            new InnerClass(){
                public void innerMethod(){
                    otherMethod();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Is there a keyword to refer to the outer class from the inner class?  Basically what I want to do is `outer.otherMethod()`, or something of the like, but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 368, accepted):

In general you use `OuterClassName.this` to refer to the enclosing instance of the outer class.

In your example that would be `a.this.otherMethod()`

Comment: can you tell why `a.otherMethod()` wont work?

Comment: @T.Todua `OuterClassName.otherMethod()` would refer to a static method, so you need `OuterClassName.this` to get the instance of the outer class.

Comment: Can OuterClassName.this be null inside an inner class, in some case?

Comment: @ApurvGupta I don't think so. Only possibility would have been if you had tried to create an anonymous inner class from static method. But if you try to use "a.this" in that case, you will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 48):

```
OuterClassName.this.outerClassMethod();
```