# Access the outer class instance within the anonymous inner class in Java

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [keyword for the outer class from an anonymous inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974/keyword-for-the-outer-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class)

I need to access the instance of the outer class within the anonymous inner class and did something like this. Can anyone clarify whether this is correct or not?

```
public class ClassA{

ClassA refernceOfClassA = this;  

    public void m(){
       //Do something
    }
    Runnable target = new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
           //Code goes here using the refernceOfClassA
           refernceOfClassA.m();      
       }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just call the method `m()` from the inner class.

```
public class ClassA{    
    public void m(){
       //Do something
    }
    Runnable target = new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
           //Code goes here using the refernceOfClassA
           m();      
       }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you even need the referenceOfClassA. You can just access properties on the outer class and call its methods normally.