# Accessing outer class variable via inner class object in main

Tags: java, nested-class

```
class Host {
    int x=2;

    class Helper {
        int x = 7;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Host ho = new Host();
        Helper he = ho.new Helper();
        System.out.println(ho.x);
        System.out.println(he.x);

    }
}
```

So here I'm getting the expected output

```
2
7
```

Now I wanted to ask that, say, I want to access `ho`'s `x` from `he`.

I.e. I want something here which will print me `2` through the Helper object `he`:

```
System.out.println(???);
```

I know there's no use of such a thing, I just want to clarify my concept of nested classes.
I figure that this should be possible, because the Helper object `he` is sort of 'binded' to the Host object `ho`. Since `he` is not possible without `ho`. From inside the Helper class I can do `System.out.println(Host.this.x);` and it works. I can't figure out how to do it from inside main.

Comment: You can't, there is no instance of `Helper` "living" into `Host` `ho`

Comment: The question has been answered over here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974/keyword-for-the-outer-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by other answers you can't. The reason lies in the way `this` is defined in the [JLS #15.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3)

> The keyword this may be used only in the body of an instance method, instance initializer, or constructor, or in the initializer of an instance variable of a class. **If it appears anywhere else, a compile-time error occurs.**

And since you can only access the enclosing instance with `this` (cf [JLS #15.8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4)), that can only be done within the inner class:

> It is a compile-time error [ to call `C.this`] if the current class is not an inner class of class C or C itself.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the time, in old versions of Java, you used `this$0` as the way to access the outer instance instead of `Host.this`. The specification has changed but the field is still available through reflection :

```
Field this$0 = he.getClass().getDeclaredField("this$0");
Host host = (Host) this$0.get(he);
System.out.println(host.x);
```

I don't know any other way (apart modifying the `Host` class to add a `getX` or `getHost` method).

Now, why isn't this access available without reflection ? I can see two possible reasons :

- they forgot
- this access from outside the instance breaks the encapsulation

Comment: @assylias I suppose it was considered it would go against encapsulation and maybe would lead to new questions regarding field access rights. It also looks a lot like how closure protect variables in some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Java concept, Host class can access inner class variable `x` where as vice versa not possible. You can do like what @Nikita Beloglazov is saying. But directly using variable, not possible

Comment: Hm. Interesting. So how do I do it in the other direction? How do I access `he`'s `x` from `ho`?

Comment: You can't as @RC in your comment saying

Comment: Oh, so I can't do it either way? I can only access their variables though their independent objects?

Comment: So what does this mean, as you said this in your reply : `Host class can access inner class variable x`

Answer (score 0):

You can create method in inner class that returns outer class:

```
class Helper {
    int x = 7;

    public Host outer() {
        return Host.this;
    }
}

// In main;
System.out.println(he.outer().x);
```

It is similar to accessing `x` inside `Helper`  but more general.