# Java Inner class - access to the variables of outer object

Tags: java

If i have a Inner class (not static) example:

```
public class A {
     int myNumber = 100;

     class B {
     }  

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         A outerObj = new A();
         B innerObj = outerObj.new B();
         System.out.println("i want the access to the variable 
                             myNumber by the innerObject"); 

     }
}
```

i mean:
i would like with the innerObject to reach the outerObject and see the variable myNumber.
I can do that just if i'm in a method of the B Class... but i would like everywhere to see the variabile of the outerObj by the inner.... it's possible?
if not why? 
thanks

Comment: There's no variable `numb`. Please clarify.

Comment: @MightyPork He probably means `myNumber`...

Comment: yes i mean myNumber sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want something like this:

```
class B
{
   private int getNum()
   {
      return myNumber;
   }

   private void setNum(int x)
   {
      myNumber = x;
   }
}
```

However, you **cannot** get access to `myNumber` from an instance of `B`, `b`, by doing `b.myNumber`.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700138/accessing-outer-class-variable-via-inner-class-object-in-main) why.

Comment: yes thi i know, but i dont want enter in the class b to read the variables of the outer obj... i would to read them directly in the main method or in other method but not of the class b

Comment: @GiovanniFar Then you could just read from class A?  What you're saying doesn't make sense to me.  You want to read the members of A without A, but with a nested class that can only be initialized by A?  But you don't want to use methods? Why?  If so, you need to access from A.

Comment: No i mean this: 
my innerObj points to the outer Obj ok ? there is a way with the innerObj to see the variabiles of the outerObject WITOUHT using the class b so WITHOUT using the class of the innerobj? i would like to know if the innerobj i can see the variable of the outerobj everywhere or just in the class b and why

Comment: @GiovanniFar Just in class `B`, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700138/accessing-outer-class-variable-via-inner-class-object-in-main) why.