# Cannot invoke "this.firePropertyChange()" on JPanel reference

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, polymorphism, matisse

Why can I not invoke `firePropertyChange()` on `this` reference?

```
    [javac] /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Legacy/src/legacy/gui/table/SelectTableFollowup.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     this.firePropertyChange("client", null, i);
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol: method firePropertyChange(String,<null>,int)
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Legacy/nbproject/build-impl.xml:923: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Legacy/nbproject/build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 4 seconds
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Legacy$
```

This is my code:

```
package legacy.gui.table;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import legacy.database.Queries;

public class SelectTableFollowup extends JPanel {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SelectTableFollowup.class.getName());
    private ClientsTable table;
    private Followup followup;
    private Select Select;
    private final Queries queries = new Queries();

    public SelectTableFollowup() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        table = new ClientsTable();
        followup = new Followup();
        Select = new Select();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(Select, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(followup, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        followupButton();
        query();
        cannotFirePropertyChangeOnThisObj();
    }

    private void cannotFirePropertyChangeOnThisObj() {
        table.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("client".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    String s = evt.getNewValue().toString();
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
                    log.info("i is " + i);
                    this.firePropertyChange("client", null, i);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private void followupButton() {
        followup.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("followup".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    try {
                        int id = table.getId();
                        queries.send(id);
                        table.updateModel();
                    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException obe) {
                        log.info(obe.toString());  //no big deal
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void query() {
        Select.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("select".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    log.info(evt.getNewValue().toString());
                    table.select(evt.getNewValue().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From Netbeans, I know that it's quite possible to invoke `this.firePropertyChange()`, for `JPanel`'s which NetBeans creates.

How is the above class any different from a Netbeans generated class? Both extend the same base class.

If I've misused any terminology, please do let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context:

```
table.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        ...
        this.firePropertyChange("client", null, i);
    }
}
```

The keyword `this` refers to the [anonymous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) inner class generated when you create a new `PropertyChangeListener` instance. This fact is explained here: [Using the this Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Take a look to this topic: [Keyword for the outer class from an anonymous inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974/keyword-for-the-outer-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class) You should replace this line for this one to refer to your panel class:

```
table.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        ...
        SelectTableFollowup.this.firePropertyChange("client", null, i);
    }
}
```

Or you can remove `this` and compiler will resolve the same for you:

```
table.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        ...
        firePropertyChange("client", null, i);
    }
}
```

Given the anonymous *inner* class doesn't have any `firePropertyChange()` method, compiler will look up for the outer class (or eventually the hierarchy tree) and chek if it has such method, which is indeed the case.

Answer (score 4):

I think the error happens in this method:

```
private void cannotFirePropertyChangeOnThisObj() {
    table.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() 

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if ("client".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                String s = evt.getNewValue().toString();
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
                log.info("i is " + i);
                this.firePropertyChange("client", null, i);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

You are invoking `firePropertyChange()` on the anonymous `PropertyChangeListener` object. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) state that it does not declare the method `firePropertyChange()`.

I think you want to invoke it on your `SelectTableFollowup` object. Then you would have to call it like this:

```
private void cannotFirePropertyChangeOnThisObj() {
    table.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() 

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if ("client".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                String s = evt.getNewValue().toString();
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
                log.info("i is " + i);
                SelectTableFollowup.this.firePropertyChange("client", null, i); // Reference this of the outer class
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Since `PropertyChangeListener` does not declare the method you could also just write `firePropertyChange("client", null, i);`.