# Why having activity name before `this`?

Tags: android

I am seeing code like this following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
```

For example, in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity), this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click) and many other more.

But is it necessary to have the class name `MainActivity` in front of the `this` pointer? I remove it and don't see any differences in the app at all. As a matter of fact, when I am reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), the Acitivity name is not being used in front of the `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not necessary except in certain cases. Those cases being when you need to refer to an outer instance from within a nested class.

For example, if you had an anonymous AsyncTask within your activity you would need to use the MainActivity.this style to refer to the activity instance.

[Keyword for the outer class from an anonymous inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974/keyword-for-the-outer-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class)