# THIS keyword within Inner class

Tags: java, android

Sorry for the basic question. But it was like 3 years ago since I encountered this case.

I have this code

```
class ParentClass {
   ...

   class InnerClass {
      ...
      // 'this' call here
      ...
   }
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could answer these questions for me:

1. How can I get the instance of ParentClass using `this` notation?
2. How can I get the instance of InnerClass using `this` notation?

Cheers!

Comment: Please read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html You have everything there: explanation, examples, everything

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question little bit.?

Comment: oh there you are! thanks Uata!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May this answer will help you out you can access parent class method and variable by like this

```
ParentClassName.this.methodname()
```

[Keyword for the outer class from an anonymous inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974/keyword-for-the-outer-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class)